# Is "settle it through a race" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

For this question

> Let's settle it _________ race.

Can we say let's settle it through a race?
Is is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more natural to this US English speaker to say that we settle it **with** a race.  For example,

> [When it's a grudge match, when there's bad blood, wouldn't I rather settle it with a few rounds of old-fashioned boxing...](https://books.google.com/books?id=VGZ7HbvqenkC&pg=PA214&dq=%22settle%20it%20with%20a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz0I2b45XSAhVBrVQKHRvdCMUQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=%22settle%20it%20with%20a%22&f=false)

"Settle it **by** _____" is also possible:

> [If any dispute arises out of this agreement the parties will attempt to settle it by negotiation.](https://books.google.com/books?id=tUVPa0esS28C&pg=PA200&dq=%22settle%20it%20by%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj898DN45XSAhWk6IMKHV-1CLUQ6AEIRzAH#v=onepage&q=%22settle%20it%20by%22&f=false)
>
> [...the entity must or can settle it by delivering shares.](https://books.google.com/books?id=WeUbBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA648&dq=%22settle%20it%20by%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9zf2L5ZXSAhXp6oMKHcAMBqYQ6AEIQjAI#v=onepage&q=%22settle%20it%20by%22&f=false)

[but when using **by** we normally use a mass noun or a gerund](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22settle%20it%20by%22), like "by ___ing" or "by means of" or "by negotiation"; using **by** with a count noun seems to be unusual, although I can't explain an exact reason why that is so.

So either "settle it **with a race**" or "settle it **by racing**" would sound fairly normal.